# how to compare a row with the user input in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Here is the code where i need to check**

```
@app.route('/inner', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def inner():
        name = request.form['name']
        password = request.form['password']
        if name == "" or password == "":
            return render_template('index.html');
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv("login.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
            for row in df:
                if row[0][0] == name and row[0][1] == password:
                    print('sucess')
                    return render_template('inner.html');
                else:
                    return render_template('index.html');
```

I dont know how exactly this has to be done but i need something like this where it compares from csv.

*login.csv*

```
name     password
admin    admin 
abc      xyz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Simplest and easiest way is to iterate through each row of the dataframe using iterrows(), Check this updated code:

```
@app.route('/inner', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def inner():
    name = request.form['name']
    password = request.form['password']
    if name == "" or password == "":
        return render_template('index.html');
    else:
        # Reading the file everytime will degrade the function performance
        df = pd.read_csv("login.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
        for index,row in df.iterrows():
            if row['name'] == name and row['password'] == password:
                print('sucess')
                return render_template('inner.html');
            else:
                return render_template('index.html');
```

Comment: if we want to store data in name and password how to store into that row

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over columns not rows in `for row in df`. If you want to iter over rows, you can access them through `.loc` or 'iloc' for positional based indexing.

```
for ind in df.index:
    row = df.loc[ind]

for ind in range(len(df.index)):
    row = df.iloc[ind]
```

I believe your code should be as follows:

```
else:
    df = pd.read_csv("login.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
    for ind in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.iloc[0, 0] == name and df.iloc[0, 1] == password:
            print('sucess')
            return render_template('inner.html');
        else:
            return render_template('index.html');
```